# Move an item of a container at the end (deque)

Tags: c++, stl, containers, deque

Is there any way to move the position of an item from a container?

I am interested of moving this item at the end of the deque that belongs to.

In the example above how can I move the second element at the end of the container?

```
std::deque<int> foo {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Comment: It is unclear what you mean. To clarify: Do you intend to move the item from the end of the container to the outside of that container?

Comment: No, I mean to change it's position in the same container, not outside of it.

Comment: You can swap the item with the last one in the container.

Comment: This is not what I want because I want to keep the order of the others.
It is like to give the least priority by moving it at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only possible solution that I have thought is the following which is much different than rotate:

```
template <typename T>
void moveToEnd(typename std::deque<T> & d, typename std::deque<T>::iterator  pos)
{
  if ( pos > d.end()-2 )
  {   
    cout << "wrong input" << endl;
    return;
  }

  for (auto i=pos; i!=d.end()-1; i++)
    swap(*i, *(i+1));
}

int main()
{

deque<int> deq {1,2,3,4,5,6};

std::deque<int>::iterator it = deq.begin()+2;
moveToEnd<int>(deq,it);
//std::rotate(deq.begin(), it, deq.end());

for (auto i=deq.begin(); i!=deq.end(); i++)
    cout<< *i << " ";

return 0;
}
```

Results with my rotate: 3 4 5 6 1 2

Results with moveToEnd: 1 2 4 5 6 3

The result that I want is to go at the end like a bubble

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to ... change [item's] position in the same container

Yes. That is what `std::swap` does for example.

If you want to keep the order of other elements so that previously last element doesn't go where the new last element was, then the operation that you're looking for is `std::rotate`. Alternatively, you can simply remove the element, and re-insert to the end.

Comment: Hello eerorika,
Thank you for your reply!
You mean std::swap, right?
 
I have updated my post. In the example that I mention how can I move the second element at the end of the container?
In the link below it mentions only the swap between two containers.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/swap-free/

Comment: @Nebula instead of using swap on the container, use it on the element.

Comment: Yes but this swaps the second element with the last element.
I would something like the second element goes at the end like a bubble. The same result as removing and push_back

Comment: Hello!
Please see my next answer to see what I wanted to do..

Answer (score 0):

You can remove your item from the deque and push it at the end

```
// be sure to have at least 6 items in your que
auto myItem = myDeque.at(5); // save the item
myDeque.erase(myDeque.begin(), myDeque.begin()+5); // remove it from que
myDeque.push_back(myItem); // insert it at the end
```

You also might use std::swap, which allows you to exchange your item with the last one.
Note that this would change the relative order of the previously last element.

Comment: This is the workarround that I am doing it right now (removing and adding again) and I do some actions twice which is not efficient